# debugging both managed c# code and unmanaged c++ code in one solution

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I have a solution with an unmanaged c++ dll project in it and a c# managed project that calls dll using PInvoke.
Is it possible to debug both managed and unmanaged code so that I see what is going on "inside" of that dll?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yup. If I'm not mistaken, it should do this automatically, as long as the profile is set to "Debug".

Edit: Oh, I forgot one thing: In the debugging options for the managed project, make sure you have the option "Enable unmanaged code debugging". Then it should step into the unmanaged code.

Comment: mmm well the breakpoints in c++ project are inactive as if symbols were not loaded.
However, managed application can be debugged correctly. Do you know what is a pattern for mixed managed/unmanaged solutions in terms of project references (dll copy) and debugging?

Comment: As I just discovered, you have to set the "Enable unmanaged code debugging" option in the debugging section of the managed project's properties, and it will let you debug unmanaged code!